# KeystoneJS custom content types

Tags: node.js, mongodb, keystonejs

I'm using keystone js cms on my recent project, this is my first time when im using any kind of cms. So, i need to make custom content/post types on the site so any one without coding experience can edit them, example website header / info page of site etc..

I've been trying to google docs and tuts of it but i haven't found anything, i think i'm misunderstanding something.

Hope you got my point.

Comment: do mean like a custom fieldtype? http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#fieldtypes

Comment: I'm aware of fieldtypes, but i mean content types. Hope this link defines it more what i mean.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you're after correctly, you want to create additional `List` definitions.

The yeoman generator creates some default ones for you (User, Post, Enquiry, etc.) but you can create as many of your own as you like by adding more files to that folder.

Each `List` you define can have any combination of fields added to it (from the available field types) so you can use them to define any type of data you need.

Keystone's default configuration will automatically import all the `.js` files in the `./models` folder, the convention is to define a single List per file. Each list you define gets its own section in the Admin UI so your users can manage their content.

The docs have an example list definition which you can copy here: http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#lists-example

Hope this points you in the right direction!